# Visual Studio 2022 Default C# (CSharp) Snippets Not Showing With Intellisense

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, code-snippets

Within the last week or so, standard C# snippets like: (ctor, propfull, for, etc.) stopped showing in IntelliSense. However, if I type ctor, then press ESC to close IntelliSense, then press TAB, it will execute the snippet. Or `edit/IntelliSense/insert snippet/Visual C#` will insert any of the desired commands.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5UBv.jpg) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jpeff.jpg) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRE1v.jpg)

Below are some of the things I have tried:

`tools/options/texteditor/advanced/default IntelliSense completion mode = automatic`

`tools/options/texteditor/C#/IntelliSense/snippets behavior = always include snippets`

`snippets manager/CSharp/Visual C#` shows all correct snippets & in the correct location
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#`

Uninstalled & reinstalled VS2022.

No installation of Jetbrains or Resharper on computer.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Code-snippets-does-not-work-on-VS2022-1/10185145?q=vs2022+snippets

Comment: Thanks Hans for the current issue log & seems like the current workaround is correcting this issue.

tools/options/texteditor/C#/IntelliSense/show new snippet experience (experimental)